Why does Pygame Mixer not work when using sudo?
I have a super simple python script:
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()

When executing this on a RaspberryPi, it works like a charm:
python mytest.py  -> OK

But when running as sudo, I get a weird error:
sudo python mytest.py  -> Not OK


pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or
directory


It's typical for the sound server to be run as the user who owns a login session, and accessed through a socket accessible only to that user. (Root can access anything, of course, but root needs to know to look for it; and if the sound server is already running and has exclusive access to the /dev entry tied to the kernel driver, nothing else -- even as root -- will be able to grab it at the same time).

(It's generally also possible to configure most audio systems to run a shared copy of the sound server as root instead of as the individual user; but how to do that depends on the distro you're running, not the hardware, and you told us your hardware but not which Linux flavor you installed on it).

my comment may not  be any helpful  but you should avoid running sudo for such scripts
